# Difference between sendkeys(keys.Down) & sendkeys(keys.Arrow_Down)

Tags: java, selenium, methods, sendkeys

What is Difference between sendkeys(keys.Down) & sendkeys(keys.Arrow_Down)
In selenium java

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference, in previous versions of selenium they were called  ARROW_UP, ARROW_LEFT, ARROW_RIGHT, and ARROW_DOWN, now they are called UP, LEFT, RIGHT,  and DOWN.

Comment: I am on the previous version and Down,Right,Up are wirked on it normal is it okay right?

Comment: Yes everything is right, in the first versions it was used with "ARROW" prefix